# Bootstrap auto generating row in php(grid system)

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get 4 thumbnails in row but in next code i will get one thumbnail in one row. How i can get 4 thumbnails in one row and next automatic create new row?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <span class="label label-warning pull-right">TOP</span>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->basePath('img/placeholder.gif') ?>" alt="..."></img>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->title); ?></h3>
                    <p>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->description); ?>
                    <br>
                    Cena: <span class="label label-success"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->price); ?></span>  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    Lokalita: <span class="label label-info"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->location); ?></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
        </a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your $products is at least 4 products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that (not tested), using a $count variable to store the number of thumbnails so far :

```
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach($products as $product) : 

    // open a new row
    if (!$count%4)
        echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">'
?>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    XXXX
</a>
<?php
    // close row if there is 4 thumbnails in it
    if ($count%4 == 3)
        echo '</div></div>';

    $count++;
endforeach; 

// close the row at the end if the last one wasn't full
if ($count%4>0)
    echo '</div></div>';
?>
```

Comment: its doing same what i have... everytime i get 1 thumbnail in one row

Comment: Thx for idea man!.. but you was have some mistakes and i edit it :) now its good :)

Comment: @user3355351 Can you please tell me what you have fixed in it?